# How to debug an activity started with an Intent?

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent, android-activity

In the project that I'm working on, we have several other modules imported in. Just so you all can visualize it better, let's say I have **M1(Module 1)** and **M2(Module 2)**. *M1* starts *M2* with `startActivity(m2Intent)`. I've got several *breakpoints* in *M1* and several others in *M2*. If I debug both modules in isolation, the active *breakpoints* are hit. Nothing out of the ordinary there. If I debug them together(meaning that the `intent` for *M2* is started by *M1*) the *breakpoints* for *M2* never hit.

One thing that's worth noting, any log printed by *M2* is visible in the *logcat* even if the *breakpoints* don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Every time I need to debug *M1* and *M2* together I have to do the following:

1. On the 1st *breakpoint* hit of *M1*, I go into `run>attach debugger to android process`
2. Make sure the `debugger settings` and `debug type` are set and selected to *M2*.
3. Now *breakpoints* for *M2* hit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know if there's a better way but it works great!